# How to count messages in Kafka topic if compaction is on?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to count messages in kafka topic in case when compaction is on. topic is created via cli, properties segment.bytes=1024 and cleanup.policy=compact are added. tried to set cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms=10 via cli but get an error java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms=10.
So my questions are:

1. how to apply compaction immediately, which configs I should add?
2. Do I understand correctly if I use KafkaProducer and KafkaConsumer from kafka client(java), producer send some messages and when consumer will get them compaction will applied(if its configured correctly), so for counting actual messages I need consume them again like ?

   `ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));`
3. Can **endOffsets** method find the latest offset for compacted messages which will show count of messages?

   `Map<TopicPartition, Long> endPartitions = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);`

thanks in advance

Comment: "Immediate compaction" is not a proper use case for Kafka. Use a KTable to build latest key-value state, not depend on the brokers to do that for you. Then you can iterate the table statestore to count records, if you need it

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks. "Immediate compaction" - I mean count after compaction. I have a job, which will run once per month and I need to count messages in topic for next processing. If KTable is good approach for that I'll try

Comment: In general, Kafka doesn't really have a way to do this without a consumer. And even if you run the consumer, a compaction could currently be running, and would cause inconsistent counts if you ran the job back to back, for example. Regarding your other question, `endOffsets` is just that. You need to subtract off the beginning offsets, and that would tell you that that many records had been produced, but lets say that returns 1000, but if all have the same key, then there should only be that one record after compaction, so the difference isnt really useful